# Laravel 5.2 - srmklive/laravel-paypal issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, plugins, paypal

I'm trying to install the plugin srmklive/laravel-paypal in my laravel project and I'm getting this error message. I don't want to remove any of the shown blocking plugins, please help me to find a solution.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install srmklive/paypal 1.0.2
    - Installation request for srmklive/paypal ~1.0 -> satisfiable by srmklive/paypal[1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.4
    - srmklive/paypal 1.0.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0|~6.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.2, 6.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.2, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.3, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.1.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.2, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.2, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.2, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.3, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.1, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.2, 4.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.3, 4.2.4].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (installed at 4.2.4) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

The laravel plugin GitHub rep is to in the link : https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check vesion phpspec/phpspec by composer :composer require phpspec/phpspec
2. file composer.json click choose Install
3. composer require srmklive/paypal:~1.0